# I want to upload multiple files to firebase and then upload the data to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, firebase-storage

So the problem is that I have to upload the multiple images array to firebase and then get the link from them to upload this into the database so the object have to be this

```
var product = {
         id: userId,
         title: productName,
         price: precio,
         description: description,
         avgRating: 5,
         ratings: 5,
         image: url,//this is the uploaded images link
    }
```

So to upload all the data I do this:
**To upload Images:**

```
const uploadImage = async (uri) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onerror = reject;
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          resolve(xhr.response);
        }
      };

      xhr.open("GET", uri);
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.send();
    });
  };



const loadData1 = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    console.log("pro 1");
    filteredUri.forEach((xUri)=>{       
      var imagId = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);                        
      uploadImage(xUri)
        .then((resolve) => {
          let ref = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref()
            .child(`images/${userId}/${imagId}`);
          ref
            .put(resolve)
            .then((resolve) => {
              console.log("Images uploaded");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              alert("Error");
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      })
    console.log("pro 2");
    await loadData2();
  };
```

**To load Data:**

```
  async function loadData2() {
//////Get Images Url
        firebase
          .storage()
          .ref(`images/${userId}`)
          .listAll()
          .then(function (result) {
            result.items.forEach(function (imageRef) {
              displayImage(imageRef);
            });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
        function displayImage(imageRef) {
          imageRef
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(function (url) {
        //////////////////////////////Load Data
              firebase
                .database()
                .ref(`productos/${userId}`)
                .set({
                  id: userId,
                  title: productName,
                  price: precio,
                  description: description,
                  avgRating: 5,
                  ratings: 5,
                  image: url,
                })
                .then(() => {
                  console.log("Data uploaded");
                  setLoading(false);
                  setTimeout(function () {
                    Alert.alert(
                      "All uploaded",
                      "All right",
                      [
                        {
                          text: "Ok",
                          onPress: () => {},
                        },
                      ]
                    );
                  }, 1000);
                  navigation.goBack();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                  alert("Error, try later");
    
                  firebase
                    .storage()
                    .ref()
                    .child(`images/${userId}`)
                    .delete()
                    .then(function () {
                      console.log("Error");
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                      console.log(
                        "error"
                      );
                    });
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
      }
```

The problem here is that excute loadData1 and then loadData2 but loadData2 doesnt wait until loadData1 finishes
So it returns this

```
//pro 1
//pro 2
//Images uploaded
//Images uploaded
//Images uploaded
```

Comment: What is the `uploadImage` function for? You have the `put()` method from Firebase SDK to upload images directly.

Comment: Oh you are right, ok I'll change it but the problem is the same help please :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `loadData2` when the image upload is complete, run it as follows.

```js
const loadData1 = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    console.log("pro 1");
    filteredUri.forEach((xUri)=>{       
      var imagId = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);                        
      uploadImage(xUri)
        .then((resolve) => {
          let ref = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref()
            .child(`images/${userId}/${imagId}`);
          ref
            .put(resolve)
            .then((resolve) => {
              console.log("Images uploaded");
              loadData2();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              alert("Error");
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      })
    console.log("pro 2");
    
  };
```

Comment: But it doesn't get the image links, thats why the functions has to be executed sequentially